# Bitmap not seeing graphics

Tags: vb.net, graphics, bitmap

I have been looking for about a week now for an answer but all in vain I have code here

```
    Dim bmap As Bitmap

    bmap = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)

    Dim g As Graphics = graphics.FromImage(bmap)

    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 100, 100)

    For q As Integer = 0 To bmap.Width - 1

        For w As Integer = 0 To bmap.Height - 1

            If bmap.GetPixel(q, w) = Color.Black Then

                bmap.SetPixel(q, w, Color.Green)

            End If
        Next

    Next

   PictureBox1.Image = bmap
```

so when I click the button it will draw the 100 by 100 black box but it will not set the pixels to green

so the bitmap is not recognizing the graphics

Comment: You want a green rectangle or to color green all the black pixels?

Comment: to color all the black pixels green

Comment: `If bmap.GetPixel(q, w).ToArgb = Color.Black.ToArgb Then...`

Comment: comparing with  bmap.GetPixel(q, w) = Color.FromArgb(&HFF000000) can also fix. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From msdn about `Color` equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx):

This method compares **more than** the `ARGB` values of the `Color` structures. 
**It also does a comparison of some state flags**. **If you want
to compare just the** `ARGB` **values of two** `Color` **structures, compare them
using the** **ToArgb** **method.**

So to compare one must use **ToArgb** method

```
 If bmap.GetPixel(q, w).ToArgb = Color.Black.ToArgb Then
```

Some internals from source codes.
We see that
For `Color.Black` which is `KnownColor` this ctor will be called

```
   internal Color(KnownColor knownColor) {
            value = 0;
            state = StateKnownColorValid;
            name = null;
            this.knownColor = (short)knownColor;
        }
```

but for `GetPixel` `Color.FromArgb(value)` is called

```
private Color(long value, short state, string name, KnownColor knownColor) {
            this.value = value;
            this.state = state;
            this.name = name;
            this.knownColor = (short)knownColor;
        }

 public static Color FromArgb(int argb) {
            return new Color((long)argb & 0xffffffff, StateARGBValueValid, null, (KnownColor)0);
        }
```

So another fix for your case can be

```
If bmap.GetPixel(q, w) = Color.FromArgb(&HFF000000) Then
```